# Proving a simple proposition of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Prove that for any Borel set $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and 
>   any $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ the set $\{x : f(x) \in A\}$ is $\Sigma$-measurable whenever the function $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.

$\textit{Proof:}$

Since $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then it is open. Let $A=(a,b)$ (with $b>a$) so that we must prove that $\{x : a<f(x)<b\}$ is $\Sigma$-measurable. But $\{x :a<f(x)<b\}$$=$$\{x : f(x)<b\}\bigcap \{x : f(x)>a\}$. But since $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable then $\{x : f(x)<b\}$ is measurable and so is $\{x : f(x)>a\}$. The intersection of measurable sets is again measurable and, therefore, the statement is proved.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all Borel sets are open.

I also pressume that $\Sigma$ contains the Borel sigma algebra.

Just prove that the collection $\{f^{-1}(A): A \in \Sigma \}$ is a sigma algebra.
  and contains the open intervals $(a,b)$(which you already did)

So this sigma algebra must contain the Borel sigma algebra.

Thus you have your conclusion.

Comment: Wouldn't my proof still work, even if we are not assuming that $A$ is open, suppose $A$ is closed; the set $\{x : f(x)\geq a\}$ is still measurable on $\Sigma$

Comment: Yes because evey open intervals is a union of closed intervals.